# Как в Google таблицах / Microsoft Excel сделать разбивку по строкам скопированной информации при вставке?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, excel-формулы

[image: При копировании на Mac os из документа Excel]

[image: Текст вставляется в Telegram построчно (каждая ячейка в новую строку)]

На Windows же тест после копирования вставляется весь в одну строку. Подскажите, в какой настройке/параметре может быть дело? Нужен результат, как на Mac os.

Comment: Мне вставка нужна уже не в Excel , а в Телеграм

Comment: Из Excel только скопировать